Center a component in another component in JavaFX
I want to dynamically center a small AnchorPane (containing the image) into a larger AnchorPane as shown below. For now, the small AnchorPane contains only an image but more controls will be added later. Statically, I am doing this by setting the top/botton/right/left Anchors. But At runtime, I want the small AnchorPane to remain vertically and horizontally centered even if the parent size changes.
Dynamically, this can be done changing the top/botton/right/left Anchors when the parent resizes, but can this be done in a simpler way, for example, is possible to set the smaller AnchorPane to be always horizontally and vertically centered?


Why use an AnchorPane, rather than a pane designed to center things (StackPane)?

@jewelsea, I have not put all components in the image above, the AnchorPane is the second child of a VBox, the first child is a toolbar, i'm tried to put the AnchorPane in a stackPane and set its alignment to Center, but it does not center

Create and post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve.

@Noor. Why use any AnchorPanes at all. Your smaller AnchorPane probably grows to fill the entire StackPane, making you think it is at the top left. Try using an outer StackPane with a VBox holding your toolbar and Image view.

I think is posible to create a method for listening Anchorpane sizes changes and reposition a child every time , but has no sense for me because stackpane has that behavior by default . It's a gui  design  problem

this solution is currently working for me: VBOX, first child is toolbar, second child is StackPane

Something like this.  No need for an AnchorPane.

package example.stackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class CenteredThing extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        var toolbar = new ToolBar(new Button("button 1"),new Button("button 2"));
        var centeredStuff = new StackPane(new Rectangle(50,50));
        VBox.setVgrow(centeredStuff, Priority.ALWAYS);
        var vbox = new VBox(toolbar, centeredStuff);
        var scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setTitle("Centered Item");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
}

